# AngularJS - Show byte array content as image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm searching into my database a image as a byte array. I want to show this content as file using the markup *image*, but it doesn't work here.

```
// Controller which get my image and put into $scope.
function MyController($scope, $http, $location) {  

    var url = '/json/FindImage?id=1';  
    $http.get(url).success(function(result) {  
        $scope.image = result.Image;  
    }  
}  

// HTML
<!-- It doesn't work -->  
<img src="{{image}}" />  
<!-- It doesn't work also -->  
<img ng-src="{{image}}" />
```

Any idea?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `ng-src` in the following format

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}">
```

Don't forget to add a sanitization filter for `data` to not be marked as `unsafe` by angular:

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ftp|blob):|data:image\//);
```

Comment: GET data:image/PNG;base64,etc.net::ERR_INVALID_URL for me

Comment: @Assem  , even am getting net::ERR_INVALID_URL. What might be the issue.

Comment: @Hema, Yes actually i guess the issue was java side. Now on front side I have <img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{myresponsejsonobject.image}}"> and java side I have a ByteArrayOutputStream object which i convert in b64 like that byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();String b64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageBytes);baos.close();  Then put my string in a json.

Comment: Hi @Assem-Hafez, where should the sanitisation filer be added?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher this should go in your config
angular.module('myApp').config(['$compileProvider',
  function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ftp|blob):|data:image\//);
  }
]);

Comment: Get a image from a function             <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{getImage('dynamicbehaviour')}}">

Answer (score 2):

If you can get your server to return the image in a base64 encoded string, you could use a [data url](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/) as the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure The Data you are returning to show as a image is converted to 
ToBase64String

In your C# code, Use Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes) and in the view use this

Answer (score -1):

The `src` attribute of `img` points to the source file of the image, it doesn't contain the actual source data. You can't do what you want this way; instead, you would have to write an image decoder in JavaScript (e.g., https://github.com/devongovett/png.js), which outputs into a `canvas` element.