# AngularJS: Binary Image not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-src` to load binary image data, however all I am getting in the console is: `GET http://localhost:3000/%7B%7D 404 (Not Found)` in the console with a broken image in the front end.

I am using the following code to load the image: `<img ng-src="{{ event.snapshot }}" />`

`event.snapshot` is lazy loaded with the following code:

```
$scope.downloadImage = function(imgReady, index) {
    if (imgReady == false) {


        for (var i = $scope.vehicles[index].events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var config = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Events/SnapShot',
                data: $scope.vehicles[index].events[i],
                cache: false
            }

            RequestService.makeApiRequest(config).success(function(j) {
                return function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.vehicles[index].events[j].snapshot = response.data;
                }
            }(i));

            console.log($scope.vehicles[index].events[i]);
        };
    }
}
```

When the user pops open an event tab, I am loading the image in. The `console.log` is showing the data as loaded, and it comes in the following style:

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCADGAoADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAA...`

I've cut the data short as it is much longer than this, do I need to perform additional massaging to the data? I am confused as to why it is not loading correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Show byte array content as image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979791/angularjs-show-byte-array-content-as-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prepend 'data:image/png;base64,' (might change depending on type) to the data for src to work for images

```
data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCADGAoADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAA...
```