# Display byte array as image

Tags: angularjs, image, byte

I want to display a byte array as an image using AngularJS.
The byte array is sent from the server to the angularJS. And when I try to display it using this HTML code:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{photos[0].photo}}">
```

AngularJS :

```
$scope.getGallery = function() {
            $http.get('gallery/'+$stateParams.id).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.photos = data;
            }).error(function(data) {
                alert("Bad");
            });
        };`
```

It just shows me an icon of an empty image.
This what it shows when I inspect the icon whith the browser :

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,STUwNGU0NzBkMGExYTBhMDAwMDAwMGQ0OMThlOTRiMTVjNzA2OTZhNzQ0MDk0YTEyNDM4YWUyMDNhOWZjNThiZmFjMjg0Z...yNjA4Mg==">
```

Comment: seems like it is not generating `src` attribute

Comment: Your data are probably incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Show byte array content as image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979791/angularjs-show-byte-array-content-as-image)