# display byte array as image in angular js

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlets

I have an image in database. I want to retreive the image and display it in web page using angular js. After fetching data i have byte array. How do i send the data to the html page. I am having issues with the below code.. Kindly help.
**When i click the link to view the image, page is sending 2 get requests to the server instead of one. It is sending request continuously for 2 times.**

Note : I have tried using the below link.. But it didn't work

[AngularJS - Show byte array content as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979791/angularjs-show-byte-array-content-as-image)

Below is my js file

```
app.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope,$http,$location) {
$scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
 var url = '/Angular/login';  
    $http.get(url).success(function(result) {  

        $scope.image = result.image;
    })  
});
//html
<img data-ng-src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{image}}">
```

Java class file

```
 public String getImage() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String byteStr=null;
    try
    {
        Connection con= DbConnect.getConnection();
        String sql ="select * from image_data where id=1";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);  
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        { 
            Blob b=rs.getBlob(2);
            byte barr[]=b.getBytes(1,(int)b.length());

             byteStr = new String(barr);
        }  
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
    return byteStr;

}
```

Servlet Code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("inside get");
    JSONObject result= new JSONObject();
    Retreive rt = new Retreive();
    result.put("image", rt.getImage());
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(result.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `element` being click?

Comment: `<img data-ng-src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{image}}"` Is the image really based64 encoded? If not, then it can not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your `image` is not base64 encoded string but still that byte array. You need to encoded it first in order to use it like this `<img data-ng-src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{image}}">`

Check the documentation [AngularJS - Show byte array content as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979791/angularjs-show-byte-array-content-as-image)

You can also try this approach https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841